# Arduino Uno: Receive MIDI data from DAW

Tags: midi

I basically want to have my Arduino accept MIDI data from my digital audio workstation, my choice is Ableton Live. I would then like it to check the received data and change the state of a digital pin accordingly. I made a pretty basic schematic to show you.
[image: Schematic]

(Just a very quick diagram, I intend to use RGB LEDs and transistors of some sort in the final product)

I would be happy using a Serial>Midi of some sort if it's the only way, but true USB MIDI would be nice.

Comment: What kind of MIDI interface hardware does your PC have? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to do it over USB. And my question is what would be the best and most appropriate way to do this, I could be sending 50-200 notes a second so needs to be relatively fast

Comment: Which Arduino are you using?

Comment: Arduino Uno R3.

Comment: So you want to make a sound to light machine eh? Is there any detail in the midi messages that is particularly important for triggering the LEDs?

Comment: Potentially ON velocity for colour in the future, but other than that, just note number.

Answer (score 1):

The R3's ATmega16U2 supports USB, so all you need to create a USB MIDI device is software.

On AVRs, you typically use the Lightweight USB Framework for AVRs ([LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php)), which has support code for both the basic USB protocol and for USB MIDI.

Comment: I'm kind of new to some of this, how would I go about using that?

Comment: LUFA has lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

For USB Midi you could use: Arduino UNO + USB Host Shield + [USBH_MIDI Library](https://github.com/YuuichiAkagawa/USBH_MIDI)

The library is specifically for the USB Host Shield. I've used this to take MIDI over USB from a digital piano and used it to control some LEDs. It's pretty strait forward to get it all working.